# Ajax button in rails - Unprocessable Entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, button

I created an ajax button to create a transaction, but when I click on it, the `Transaction.count` doesn't increment.

I have three models : `User`, `Product` and `Transaction`

User and Product have a many to many association through transaction, that belongs to both.

Here is the create method in my **app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb**

```rb
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:transaction][:product_id])
  @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
  @transaction.save!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @product }
    format.js
  end
end

def transaction_params
  params.require(:transaction).permit(:product_id, :start_date, :end_date)
end
```

Here is my button view **app/controllers/transactions/buttons/_wants.html.erb**

```rb
<div class="wants_button product_<%=product.id%>">
  <% if current_user %>
    <%= form_for(current_user.transactions.build(product_id: product.id),
                                              remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field :product_id %></div>
      <%= f.submit t('button.ownership.create'), class: "btn btn-success btn-small" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And here my **app/views/transactions/create.js.erb**

```rb
$(".wants_button.product_<%=@product.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('transactions/ownership/buttons/wants_not', product: @product)) %>")
```

At least, what returns the server :

```rb
Started POST "/transactions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-22 16:05:52 +0200
Processing by TransactionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "transaction"=>{"product_id"=>"239"}, "commit"=>"Acquisition"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'A0J7Ii29W7NPO0ECCccm6g' LIMIT 1
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? ORDER BY products.created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "239"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 12ms
```

Do you know what could interfere with the creation of a transaction ?

Comment: Would it hurt to write `new` and then `save` and then check validation errors? Or even `save!` to get it in your face as an exception?

Comment: Not sure I'm clear on what you're trying to do.  What do you want to increment when the button is clicked?  You mean it's just not saving the transaction?

Comment: I'm trying to create a transaction with a button, but the transaction is never created. I updated my question, thanks to Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem. Make sure you are sending the CSRF authenticity token - using rails' `form_tag` or what have you automatically includes it for you, but manual AJAX request do not.